# catchError seems to require two arguments instead of one

Tags: rxjs6

I am reading the source code of `catchError`. I notice that it is defined as follows: It seems it takes as argument a function which takes two arguments and returns an `Observable` - `selector: (err: any, caught: Observable<T>) => ObservableInput<R>`

```
export function catchError<T>(selector: (err: any, caught: Observable<T>) => never): MonoTypeOperatorFunction<T>;
export function catchError<T, R>(selector: (err: any, caught: Observable<T>) => ObservableInput<R>): OperatorFunction<T, T | R>;
export function catchError<T, R>(selector: (err: any, caught: Observable<T>) => ObservableInput<R>): OperatorFunction<T, T | R> {
  return function catchErrorOperatorFunction(source: Observable<T>): Observable<T | R> {
    const operator = new CatchOperator(selector);
    const caught = source.lift(operator);
    return (operator.caught = caught as Observable<T>);
  };
}
```

But in the examples of usage of `catchError`, it seem to take a function with one argument `catchError(err => of[])`. How come the examples don't need the second argument `caught`?